# No Sound in Space

Tags: word, pattern, cryptic-clues, english

I hear there is no sound in space.

But you are not in space so should have no trouble solving these.

*(These are related/themed cryptic clues, more or less. They may or may not be valid or fair, in the strictest sense. But there are a couple patterns so that shouldn’t get in your way.)*

Take the answer with an invalid first letter and subtract the last letter to form a relevant word.

- Align ball-point pens into boxy shapes
- Memory and communication system interconnected four ways
- Many-sided enclosure missing chatty occupant
- Lumberjack questions benefit of hatchets versus saws, which can make a smooth, tall line
- Seabirds struggling to form V’s
- Round about way of asking monarch to take a bath
- Response after spotting hilarious attempt to pitch a tent
- Gollum impersonator cut due to sickness going around
- Red animal wearing pumps
- Deceitful cats restin' in straight rows
- Mouth shape formed without teeth, gums, or tongue
- Coniferous tree bent in reverse
- Bow low to hear this proclamation of a six-year-old upon seeing big trucks

Here are the word lengths, in no particular order:
(5), (5), (6), (6), (7), (7), (7), (9), (9), (10), (13), (1-4), (1-4)

*Warning: originally I had clue 1 as "... boxy shape (5)" but added an 's' as it seemed to read better. I think I inadvertently broke the definition (see commentary); feel free to read as "... curves (6)" or something. Since it's unclear, I'll confirm we are looking for 'cubics'.*

Hint

> Scrawled on the side of the side of the puzzle you make out part of a message: "Eu#### wuz heer"

Hint 2

> For #5, the splitter is 'to'. All other words are important. The definition can "form V's" in a certain abstract sense. Answers given so far are maybe valid but unlikely to lead to an overall solution.
>  Notes: @Prem has part of the wordplay for #13 hidden in their post.  Ellipse can be pronounced with an 'ah' where I am from. If you add a drawl...

Hint 3

> With what you now know, re-examine the introduction

Hint 4

> For most or all clues, the wordplay is essentially the entire sentence, but for the red animal clue, that is a bit misleading. The relevant wordplay is "red animal". The animal happens to be wearing pumps in the clue, but that is not relevant and quite silly. This should be doable as I googled "red animal" and saw a picture of it.

Hint 5

> Why wear pumps? Perhaps as a joke, for his best friend is getting married and he is going to crash the (??) party...
>  The missing geometric entity is well known to preschoolers. The red animal, not at all.

Comment: It would help if a couple of examples are given ; otherwise we will be stuck in decoding the instructions ! I think the third one is "Polygon - Poly = gon ; subtracting the last letter gives : go" but this has only 2 letters which is not in the word lengths list !

Comment: Instructions can be ignored for a while. In theory, as you progress, insights will emerge.

Comment: The clues I've be able to solve so far all seem to involve homonyms -- I don't want to rude but can I ask what dialect of English your using?

Comment: American... non-native speakers may want to skip this... will tag

Comment: I leave my answers in these comment then for better speakers to use :)  I have: 1) rot13(Phovpf (PHR + OVPF) gubhtu obkl funcrf ner npghnyyl phobvqf naq phovpf ner pheirf(?)); 3) rot)13(Cbyltba ("Cbyyl tbar")); 4) rot13(L-nkvf ("Jul nkrf?")) and 10) rot13(Cunynakrf (Snhk ylakrf)).  For the seabirds in 5) I was looking at both Thvyyrzbgf/Thvyyrzrgf and rot13(Thyyf/Thyyvrf) thought I think not either are right.  Overall there seems to be a rot13(trbzrgevpny gurzr), which the hint supports rot13(Rhpyvq)

Comment: I am not great at English either - someone can maybe confirm whether cubics is or is not a valid plural for cubic (boxy) (I got yes from google but who knows), if not I can edit that one to be clearer. Glad you figured it out though!

Comment: @MOehm Good find! The two patterns identified rule out the current V's answer, and the third and final feedback mechanism should emerge as a few more are spotted. Recall we are ultimately looking for an invalid first letter.

Comment: Getting to the home stretch! A solution matrix and rubber band should help with the rest.

Comment: Oops looking at your basically correct answer for the tent clue, I see I had the wrong letter count. Apologies! Fixed... hope it didn't waste too much time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "cryptic clues" are ...

> ... all homophones, as indicated by the title and the question. The answers are all related to geometry.

In particular: (Ⓝ found by Narushiteli; Ⓢ found by samm82; Ⓟ guessed by Prem.)

> Align ball-point pens into boxy shapes
>  — queue bics / CUBICS
>  Memory and communication system interconnected four ways
>  — ROM bus / RHOMBUS Ⓝ
>  Many-sided enclosure missing chatty occupant
>  — POLYGON / Polly gone
>  Lumberjack questions benefit of hatchets versus saws, which can make a smooth, tall line
>  — why axes / Y-AXIS Ⓝ
>  Seabirds struggling to form V’s
>  — trying gulls / TRIANGLES
>  Round about way of asking monarch to take a bath
>  — CIRCUMFERENCE / Sir, come for rinse
>  Response after spotting hilarious attempt to pitch a tent
>  —  I saw silly / ISOSCELES
>  Gollum impersonator cut due to sickness going around
>  — serk (Andy Serkis, "cut") ill / CIRCLE
>  Red animal wearing pumps
>  — hart / HEART
>  Deceitful cats restin' in straight rows
>  — lions / LINES
>  Mouth shape formed without teeth, gums, or tongue
>  — ELLIPSE / all lips Ⓟ
>  Coniferous tree bent in reverse
>  — yew bent / U-BEND
>  Bow low to hear this proclamation of a six-year-old upon seeing big trucks
>  — SEMICIRCLE / semis are cool Ⓢ

The first letters of these words so far spell out:

> C R P͜ Y T C͜ I C͜ H L E͜ U S
>  C R Y P T I C H C L U E S
>
>  This looks like **cryptic clues** with some adjacent letter pairs swapped.
>
>  The H from HEART is the odd one out. If we remove the last letter, as per the instructions, we get **HEAR**, which is relevant to the puzzle: Homophones are words that are the same in hearing.

Comment: Extremely close, but I'd be lyin' if I said it was 100%

Comment: Well, an answer with so many blanks shouldn't really be "100%", As I said above, I find this hard to get into, even though the mechanism and the theme are clear, so I'm putting this out here so that others who are more "on your wavelength" than I am may solve it.

Comment: Well, your answer contains two 9-letter words while there should only be one, so I guess one of them is wrong?

Comment: My response was a hint for whoever takes over... they are correct that 'b...' can't fit the anagram and also can't be the final word. Rest is on track.

Comment: Memory and communication system is rot13(eubzohf (EBZ + OHF)) I think.  And the seabirds now seem likely to be rot13(greaf (gheaf)) though I would have expect U's instead of V's in clue I think.

Comment: The parsing of the "Bow low...." clue is probably rot13("frzvf ner pbby" be "frzvf - fb pbby")

Comment: rot13(guvf vf ol n ybat fubg, ohg nphgr, orpnhfr erq navznyf yvxr sbkrf ner phgr abjnqnlf)

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison: Hm, yes, a long shot.

Comment: with the recent clue.,... could a red animal be rot13(cnaqn)? 5 letters and comes up in the google search :)

Comment: @Elpharya: So that's why rot13(sver ratvarf ner pnyyrq cnaqn pnef) `:) `. But the image search was the most useful part of the new hint, yes. My working theory for the red animal is: rot13(Jr ner ybbxvat sbe n ubzbcubar bs gur erq navzny, juvpu svgf jvgu gur trbzrgel gurzr. Erzbivat gur ynfg yrggre fubhyq tvir fbzrguvat gung svgf jvgu gur gvgyr, fb rvgure fbzrguvat zrnavat fcnpr be fbzrguvat zrnvat fvyrapr. Gur fcnpr pbhyq fb qbhoyr freivpr nf fcnpvat orgjrra gur "pelcgvp pyhrf".) Since that hasn't led anywhere so far, that theory is probably wrong ...

Comment: (And I sincerely hope that the rot13(ubzbcubar jr'er ybbxvat sbe vfa'g sbk / sbphf).)

Comment: It is similar to a firetruck...  But you are both correct neither of those lead to a logical final word.

Comment: This feels like a long shot, but could "Red animal wearing pumps" be rot13(GVPXF? Gvpxf pna or erq, n gvpx znex vf n purpxznex, naq gvpx = chzc va gur frafr bs "gb guebo be chyfngr", nppbeqvat gb [JbeqUvccb](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/pumps.html). Nf sbe uvag 5, cerfpubbyref jbhyq yvxryl or zber snzvyvne jvgu n purpxznex guna n gvpx. Abg fhcre fher nobhg guvf, fvapr "gvpx" vfa'g nf zhpu bs n trbzrgel grez nf gur bgure fbyhgvbaf ner).

Comment: @samm82 Good guess, but no; I've left an awful lot of clues though it's a tricky one. We're looking for a 5 letter well known term similar to the others (and defined by "pumps") that is a homophone of a red animal, whose first four letters are highly relevant to the puzzle.

Comment: I think I have it now. But ... rot13(vf n urneg ernyyl n trbzrgevpny funcr? V qba'g guvax guvf ernyyl svgf gur "Rhpyvqrna trbzrgel" gurzr. Nyfb, gur erq navzny va dhrfgvba jbhyq or xabja gb zbfg cerfpubbyref, ng yrnfg urer va Prageny Rhebcr.). Anyway, the rest fits nicely, so I'm pretty sure this must be it.

Comment: Great solve! Euclid was a hint but I was just clueing geometric terms in general, sorry if that threw you. Each clue is missing a homophone indicator"I ****", if that helps the final answer make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

RANDOM thoughts:

EUCLID + Not in SPACE : gives PLANE (AND SOLID ?) GEOMETRY

Many-sided enclosure [ Polygon ] ; chatty occupant [ Parrot , with common name Poly ] ; missing [ meaning : gone ]

Seabirds form V [ seagulls, geese, ???? ] ; struggling [ opposite of ease ] gives geese = gease = g+ease ; Alternative : Obtuse Goose ?

Gollum impersonator [ Cara Delevingne ???? No way; It is not GEOMETRY ! ]

Mouth shape formed without teeth, gums, or tongue [ Ellipse ]

Deceitful cats [ not Cheetahs, but Lions  == Lines ! ] ; resting in straight rows [ Parallel Lines ! ]

Round about way of asking monarch to take a bath [ Sir, Cool ! == Circle ]

Response after spotting hilarious attempt to pitch a tent [ Try at an angle == Triangle ; Alternative : Reflex Angle == Reflects ]

Memory and communication system interconnected four ways [ Square with 4 corners ]

Coniferous tree bent in reverse [ It might be shaped like a SPEAR == SPERE == SPHERE ; Alternative : CONICS or SEMI CIRCLE ]

UPDATES : collection & collation using the above & from other folks:
@M Oehm & @Narushiteli

[[ Oh, I see that @M Oehm has made his own updates, while I was attempting the same ! ]]

> Align PENS == CUBICS

> Memory System == RHOMBUS

> Enclosure == POLYGON

> Lumberjack == Y-AXIS

> Seabirds == ARC TIC Terns ?? == ARC

> Monarch == CIRCUMFERENCE

> Pitch a tent == ISOSCELES

> Gollum == CIRCLE

> RED =+ ??

> Cats =+ Parallel Lines

> Mouth == ELLIPSE

> Coniferous tree == U-TURN Or SEMICIRCLE or CONIC

> Big trucks == ??

Comment: I like the brainstorming!  The title/intro is relevant to each clue, and in the same way(s). That may help with direction. Cats is a great place to start, but not sure 'resting in straight rows' applies to a cheetah. : )

Comment: Love the circle idea! Unfortunately it may not meld with the final constraints (word lengths/final word). Good find with the lips!